# Событие на изменение списка гугл аккаунтов

Tags: android, google-account

Может существует какое событие, которое кидается в тот же броадкастресивер, когда пользователь меняет список google аккаунтов на своём устройстве - добавляет/удаляет?

Comment: Никогда не требовалось такое, но вот что я нашел :    
AccountManager.addOnAccountsUpdatedListener    
Далеко не уверен, что это то, что надо.    
Если не в тему, то извиняюсь...